# Copying SSIS packages from one azure database to another azure database

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, etl

I have one database on azure we will call it mydatabase.database.windows.net and that has no SSIS packages on it.

I also have a virtual machine running a database on azure that I will call VM-Myvm-SQL I have copied the database over but now I need to copy the SSIS packages over.  When I attempt to do this I get the following error (using the Integration Services Deployment Wizard)

[image: SSIS Error]

Just in case the screenshot doesn't come through very well here is the error in text

> There is no available node.  Please check node status on the monitoring page of the ADF portal and ensure that at least one node is running 1 and try again.  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 50000)

So I am not sure why I keep getting this error.

I am attempting to use SSMS to do the copying but I am up for suggestions at this point.

**EDIT**

I have created an .ispac for the SSIS project and attempted to "deploy" it to the mydatabase.database.windows.net database and received the same error.

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify, you are copying from _where_ to _where_ (Azure SQL > SQL VM or SQL VM > Azure SQL)? The error implies you are trying to copy into an Azure SQL database that doesn't have an associated SSIS runtime. You basically need to create an instance of _Azure Data Factory v2_ and set up a SSIS runtime.

Comment: Your packages need "compute" - something that does the work. Azure SQL only has compute for database activities, not SSIS activities. An ADF SSIS runtime is a managed VM that you pay for that has the required compute. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-ssis-integration-runtime.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I believe that you are correct.  As I was researching the error in depth, I read the microsoft docs on azure data factories and I am thinking along the same lines as you.  I need to create that and then they will move.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As Nick McDermaid pointed out I need to create an Azure Data Factory in order to pull the SSIS packages from one instance to another.  This is what needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

Check Azure-SSIS Integration runtime is running.